# controlling transitions when adding and removing classes

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm adding a class to fade away some text. See a basic fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg8rp0fo/

HTML

```
<p class="fadeup">some text here</p>
```

CSS
    .go {
      transition: all 250ms linear;
      transform: translateY(-20px);
      opacity: 0;
    }

JS / JQuery

```
var i = 0;

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if( e.keyCode == 32 && i == 0 ) {
        $('.fadeup').addClass('go');
  } else if( e.keyCode == 32 && i == 1 ) {
    $('.fadeup').removeClass('go');
  }
    i++;
}
```

I want to later remove the class and have the content fade down/in again. Currently, it just reappears with no transition/translate.

How can I make it reappear with a transition/translate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the CSS transition to the `.fadeup` class:

```js
//switched to click for demo
document.body.onclick= function(e) {
    $('.fadeup').toggleClass('go');
}
```

```css
.go {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
  color: red;
}
.fadeup {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="fadeup">
  some text here
</p>
```

The issue is you're adding the transition to the `go` class, so when it's removed, the transition is removed as well.

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwtdhp31/)

Comment: Thanks for the response - it works as expected. For me and others, would you kindly explain why it's required to put the transition with the original class?

Comment: @jerrysam I did. If you are applying the transition with a class, then _remove that class_, you remove the transition as well